# Different behaviour when split a string using | and /

Tags: java

When i split the String as below,

```
String s1 = "id::34|desc::test";
String s2 = "id::34/desc::test";

String [] s1a = s1.split("|");
String [] s2a = s2.split("/");
```

Why the s1a array contains elements for each character of s1 where s2a only has two elements which are id::34 and desc::test.

I am expecting s1a also have two elements.

Answer (score 8):

`String.split()` takes a *regex*. `|` is a special character in *regex* engine, you need to escape it using `\\|` or use `Pattern.quote()`.